# Можно ли будет продолжать пользоваться телеграмом после блокировки

Tags: telegram

У меня сложный вопрос.

Жена спрашивает меня, что делать, когда заблокируют телеграмм - сможет ли она дальше общаться с теми, кто уже установил программу и с кем она давно переписывается.

Или ей надо валить в другие мессенджеры, которые не будут блокировать (какие?).

Или надо спешно начать репостить советы "у нас есть прокси для телеграма, передай всем друзьям" (примеры не привожу, чтобы не пиарить, возможно это мошенники, а возможно что и сервера спецслужб)

Я ищу техническую информацию по вопросу, которая поможет принять решение по тому, что делать дальше. Есть уже сложившаяся компания девочек, которые пользовались приложением и обсуждали ноготки и лачки, теперь они <s>пособницы терористов</s> пищат и спрашивают совета что делать.

Я рассчитываю на то, что данный вопрос будет воспринят серьёзно и без флуда (я прекрасно понимаю, что такое чрезмерно широкий вопрос, оффтопичный вопрос или "вызывающий бесконечные дискуссии"). И понимаю, что и в [чатике про политику](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43839112#43839112) вопрос не формат и в [основном чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43839302#43839302) неформат и на сайте найдётся масса желающих закрыть вопрос или зафлудить его.

И всё же я попрошу постараться придерживаться правил конструктивной беседы. Если вам хочется пофлудить - пишите в комментариях к вопросу (я думаю, что это скоро выделят в отдельный чат и я впишу ссылку, куда идти флудерам), если у вас есть материала на полноценный ответ - пишите.

Мы обсудили в чате, как можно привести вопрос из общего (расплывчатого) к конкретным техническим вопросам, попробую составить список того, что меня интересует:

1. Как технически осуществляется блокировка телеграмма (поскольку ещё такого не было - то вероятно можно пояснить, как это делалось с сайтами и описать возможные сценарии для блокировки телеграмма). Я вот не знаю, что там за протокол внутри, слышал только, что всё защищено.
2. Можно ли вообще заблокировать телеграмм и насколько правдивы разговоры кухарок, что такой протокол заблокировать невозможно ([например](https://varlamov.ru/2437527.html): При этом в Ассоциации электронных коммуникаций (РАЭК) считают, что мессенджер «Телеграм» не может быть заблокирован полностью.)
3. Можно ли рассчитывать, что есть дополнительные технические средства (прокси?), через которыми можно будет пользоваться телеграмом некоторое время, пока не уйдёшь в другие мессенджеры. Есть ли какие-то прокси от самого телеграмма? Есть ли способы проще чем "купи себе VPN за бугром и ходи туда"
4. Какие есть альтернативные клиенты, к которым нет претензий у гос. органов. Альтернативные - это читай "массовые", а не клиенты которые никто не знает. Мне домохозяйкам дальше советовать, поэтому клиент нужен в первую очередь массовый (чтобы выше вероятность была, что там уже есть другие знакомые) и простой.

И не совсем технические. Какая правовая ответственность установлена за то, если я и дальше продолжу пользоваться запрещённым мессенджером?

Update. Выделено в отдельные вопросы:

- [Какие ключи требуют у телеграмма?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/810503/213987)

Comment: https://tjournal.ru/45750-unblock-tlgrm 
вот здесь немного как пользоваться в случае блокировки

Answer (score 3):

> Как технически осуществляется блокировка телеграмма (поскольку ещё такого не было - то вероятно можно пояснить, как это делалось с сайтами и описать возможные сценарии для блокировки телеграмма). Я вот не знаю, что там за протокол внутри, слышал только, что всё защищено.

Телеграм реализует свой собственный протокол поверх tcp / tcp+http, поэтому блокировка возможна на уровне адреса / адреса и порта. В протоколе предусмотрена поддержка получения адресов всех известных точек подключения, поэтому в случае блокировки лично я ожидаю ежедневную смену адресов, которые провайдеры просто не будут успевать блокировать, в этом случае ежедневно подключающийся и обновляющий список эндпоинтов клиент будет всегда на связи. Тем не менее, это игра в прятки, а не спасение, для дальнейшего спокойного использования придется использовать медиатора для подключения в том или ином виде (http-прокси или vpn). Случаев какой-либо ответственности за использование подобных технологий пока не было, если не считать историю с Tor и Богатовым.

> Есть ли какие-то прокси от самого телеграмма?

Прямо от телеграма нет (но можно ожидать в будущем некоторый сервис, который будет анонсировать те же айпишники телеграма, но сам не будет иметь формального отношения к телеграму и потому не может быть заблокирован, как это было с "красной кнопкой" во времена блокирования блога Навального), но есть компании, которые нацелены на [предоставление таких услуг](https://www.google.ru/search?q=telegram%20vpn).

> И не совсем технические. Какая правовая ответственность установлена за то, если я и дальше продолжу пользоваться запрещённым мессенджером?

Насколько понимаю, вся ответственность на самом деле на мессенджере за эм его присутствие (но это не точно).