# Как устроены ключи шифрования Telegram?

Tags: telegram

Вопрос по устройству протокола telegram и ключей шифрования.

Спецслужбы просят у телеграмма ключи и настаивают, что это требование не идёт вразрез Конституции РФ: мы не спрашиваем сообщения пользователей, мы просим только ключи.

Тогда пардон что это за такие бесполезные ключи вообще? Ими ничего нельзя расшифровать? И вообще, как устроены эти ключи: на каждого пользователя телеграм хранится ключ и ФСБ требует шесть ключей по уголовным делам о терроризме? Или они хотят некий золотой ключ, которым можно будет расшифровать любое сообщение всех ста миллионов пользователей телеграмма?

Ссылки по теме:

- [Тинькоф журнал. Телеграм не смог оспорить приказ ФСБ в суде. Что это значит](https://journal.tinkoff.ru/news/telegram-block/)

Comment: ими можно расшифровать имея доступ к устройству пользователя

Comment: @D-side Вопрос по устройству протокола телеграм, вопрос по устройству ключей -- не относится к программированию?????? Я в шоке.

Comment: Точно так. О ключах -- пожалуйста. Но об их связи с конституционным правом и о законности действий ФСБ это уже к юристу.

Comment: @D-side Для чего мне нужен ответ на данный вопрос выходит за рамки, но если вам так будет угодно - могу вычеркнуть "пытаюсь понять" и вставить "хочу написать свой клиент", будет лучше? Вы отзовёте свой голос за закрытие?

Comment: Я не думаю, что кого-то реально волнует, для чего именно вам это нужно и что именно вы хотите понять. Но присутствие таких формулировок в вопросе воспринимается как часть вопроса, даже если вы в уме понимаете, что это оффтопик и на это не следует ждать отета. На мой взгляд, лучше выкинуть эти части вовсе и оставить чисто технический вопрос об устройстве протокола (поскольку MTProto открыт, такой вопрос был бы/будет онтопиком).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cогласно [общим часто задаваемым вопросам](https://telegram.org/faq#q-do-you-process-data-requests) можно кое-что узнать о ключах для **хранящейся на серверах информации**:

- Секретные чаты там не хранятся вовсе. О ключах и речи не идёт.
- Для несекретных чатов они утверждают, что распределяют ключи по нескольким юрисдикциям, чтобы для раскрытия какой-либо информации потребовались распоряжения судов **из нескольких сразу**. Чтобы такое произошло, должно произойти нечто экстраординарное.

Согласно [часто задаваемым вопросам для технарей (technically inclined)](https://core.telegram.org/techfaq) можно сделать некоторые выводы о возможностях **расшифровки передаваемого трафика**:

- Из-за того, что при передаче повсюду используются ключи, согласованные по [протоколу Диффи-Хеллмана (ДХ)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), если сервер Telegram не сохраняет сессионных ключей (что он теоретически может, но вряд ли делает), то **расшифровка ранее записанных данных скорее всего невозможна**, т. к. и сервер и клиент могли уже давно забыть к ним ключ.
- У Телеграма есть **приватный [RSA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA)-ключ для проверки подлинности сервера**, публичный "брат" которого зашит в клиенты. При наличии этого приватного ключа возможно устроить [MITM-атаку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), заставив клиентов в подконтрольной сети считать собственный сервер подлинным сервером Telegram, из-за чего клиенты будут считать канал доверенным и приступят к согласованию сессионных ключей *с самозванцем*, который в свою очередь сможет от лица клиента связаться с настоящим сервером.
- У Телеграма есть **сессионные [ДХ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)-ключи** для общения с **конкретными клиентами** (а от одного *аккаунта* может подключиться *несколько клиентов*) об **облачных чатах** (где нет оконечного шифрования). Их нет смысла сохранять, когда можно в любой момент договориться о новом, поэтому, вероятнее всего, хоть этот ключ и существует, его нет смысла раскрывать, т. к. действителен он будет недолго.
- **Для *секретных* чатов [ДХ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)-ключи генерируются для защиты взаимодействия не с сервером, а непосредственно с адресатом**. Так что серверы ни на каком этапе не получают готового ключа и не могут их выработать даже имея записанный трафик процедуры согласования ключа. Потому что это [Диффи-Хеллман](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Поскольку Telegram трубит о максимальной приватности, есть основания полагать, что сессионных ключей они не сохраняют. Исходя из всего этого, ФСБ могут интерсовать два вида ключей, т. к. это единственные ключи с достаточным временем жизни, чтобы их имело смысл получать заранее:

- Приватный [RSA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA)-ключ сервера — да, им нельзя ничего расшифровать, но с его помощью можно получить сессионный ключ у настоящего сервера Telegram и расшифровать данные, которые можно с его помощью запросить: якобы клиентом у настоящего сервера. Т. е. выполнить [MITM-атаку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).
- Ключи шифрования (неизвестного типа) данных на жёстких дисках серверов для **облачных** чатов (секретные существуют в расшифрованном виде лишь на клиентских устройствах), если вдруг удастся заполучить данные с дисков из серверов Telegram. Сколько их и какова область каждого ключа, из-за закрытости серверного кода Telegram достоверно не известно, клиенты с этими ключами никак не работают; теоретически там может и не быть шифрования. Эти ключи имеют хоть какой-то смысл при наличии, скажем, дисков из серверов. И даже в этом случае может подложить свинью полнодисковое шифрование.

---

Разумеется, я предполагаю, что протокол Диффи-Хеллманна и RSA достаточно криптостойки в тех местах, на которые в них рассчитывают. Если их всё же проломят, устойчивость Telegram будет меньшей из проблем, которые в результате этого всплывут. На этих протоколах основывается львиная доля взаимодействий в интернете — HTTPS, например.

Answer (score 8):

Судя с этого документа ["Пояснение специалиста №1"](http://www.agora.legal/fs/a_delo2doc/48_file_7_Telegram_Shchurov_121217.pdf) следует, что для шифрования трафика используется Диффи-Хеллман (генерация общего секрета), RSA (аутенфикация), AES (шифрование). Другими словами, эта связка дает такой же уровень безопасности, как набор шифров в TLS: `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_...`

Под передачей ключей скорее всего имеют ввиду передачу приватного RSA ключа сервера. (В случае с TLS это была бы передача приватного ключа от сертификата). Люди, имеющие этот ключ, смогут расшифровывать (и изменять) трафик при помощи man-in-the-middle. При этом, если у них будет сохраненный ранее трафик, они не смогут его расшифровать в будущем с приватным ключом (как `perfect forward secrecy` в TLS).