# Как работает шифрование?

Tags: шифрование, криптография

Как работает шифрование? То есть каким образом шифруются те же сообщения в телеграме?

Comment: Вам пересказать то, что написано здесь? https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description

Comment: Касательно именно Телеграма я [недавно рассказывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810626/181100). Если вас интересует не только он, то вопрос стоит уточнить, т. к. шифрование разное бывает, об этом целые книги пишут. А если вас интересует именно Телеграм, то это дубликат.